# Getting a "ComponentActivatorException" using Castle Windsor from a .net 4.0 application using a .net 2.0 component

Tags: .net-4.0, castle-windsor, mixed-mode

I have an application which is being developed in VS2010, and makes use of the Castle-Windsor IoC, through a configuration file.

One of the components I am registering, also developed in VS2010, references a .net 2.0 component (LeadTools), so recompiling the 2.0 project isn't an option. When the wrapping component's registration is done, a "ComponentActivatorException" is raised, which wraps a "System.TypeInitializationException", which in turn wraps a "System.IO.FileLoadException" with a message of "Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information."

I have added the runtime declaration to the application's configuration file, as so:

```
<!-- useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy is needed for LEADTools-->
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" />
</startup>
```

This works fine if the wrapping component isn't registered in Windsor, however, it does appear to disregard the directives otherwise.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the full exception stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to using "define"s and "if"s within the configuration file, per the [MicroKernel documentation](http://castleproject.org/container/documentation/trunk/usersguide/defines.html). Removing all of those elements from the App.Config file allowed the components to be instantiated, whether or not they were registered in the Windsor container.

Comment: cool. Glad you were able to solve the issue. Could you create a reproduction of the issue, and post it to Castle group, so that we can see if there's anything  that can be done to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using registration via XML?

What happens if you register the component in code?

Can you try to reproduce the issue without error?

call `Type.GetType("assembly qualified name of the type from .net 2.0 assembly");`

Comment: Unfortunately, registering the component through code yields the same results, with a slightly shorter stack trace (no Windsor exceptions). Trying Type.GetType() also raises a "System.IO.FileLoadException", when done through the same application. It's almost as though the activation policy isn't being taken into consideration for some reason.

Comment: This suggests it's not really a Windsor issue - rather, perhaps a bug in the policy, which does not get taken into account when using reflection to load a library? (just guessing)